# Problem converting KML file to .lyr

Tags: arcgis-10.0, kml, convert

I have a problem in converting  KML files into lyr ones with ArcGIS 10.
I do all the steps perfectly but the conversion fails and the red check mark appears. It is surprising that when I repeat the steps for more than 10 or 20 times eventually it works and the green check mark appears!
I have the same problem with different KML files. what solution do you suggest to overcome this problem?
 thanks a lot

Comment: please provide the version of ArcGIS. and provide the method you are using to create the lyr file. and a screen shot if possible.